# Why is the assignment operator = not listed under operators in the Python official doc on lexical analysis?

Tags: python, delimiter, assignment-operator, lexical-analysis

I was reading through the Python lexical specification from the [offical docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters). I was surprised to discover that the assignment operator `=` is not listed under the [operators' section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators). Many other tutorials on the internet claim that `=` is an assignment operator. [This W3 schools article](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp) for instance says that it is an assignment operator.

However, it is listed under the [delimiters' section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters).
This section mentions that "The second half of the list, the augmented assignment operators, serve lexically as delimiters, but also perform an operation." However, it only ever talks about the "augmented assignment" operator. There is no special note about why the `=` operator exists in the delimiter section.

In my understanding, delimiters are tokens that are used to group things such as items in a list or a dictionary. That explains why brackets `[]` and curly braces `{}` are delimiters. I also know that they serve as punctuations to separate delineate multiple objects in a function argument for instance. So it makes sense to include commas `,` and colons `:` in that section.

**How is an assignment operator a delimiter and not an operator?**
The python specification is the canon, which implies that the other articles on the internet (including the W3 schools' article linked above) are wrong. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Because it's not an operator; assignment isn't an expression (except for https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), it's a statement, and `=` is a delimiter in that statement: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an operator, but part of the syntax of an [assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). In (for example) C, you can do things like `while((c = getchar()) != EOF)`, but before the "walrus" operator (`:=`) was introduced, you could not do that in Python.